# c# xmldocument load access violation

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio, code-behind

I am trying to load a xml file from c# in the code behind of a windows forms application. This is the code I use:

```
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.Load("file.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode obj in xdoc.SelectNodes("/enabledobjects/object/*"))
        {
            RadListDataItem item = new RadListDataItem();

            item.Text = obj["objectname"].InnerText;
            item.Value = obj["value"].InnerText;

            DropDownList.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

When i run debug the program, the I gent no errors. The program starts like it should for a few seconds. Then it carashes and finishes the debugging. Visual Studio shows following message:

```
The program '[6728] Daten Archivar.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I have full administrator privileges. The file is saved in the same folther the exe is saved with full access for everyone. I have no Idea why I cant access it.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<enabledobjects>
    <object>
      <objectname>John</objectname>
      <value>Carter</value>
    </object>
</enabledobjects>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code using the VS-debugger? Set breakpoints and step through it. It seems you are accessing an object that is not properly initialized, if at all...

Comment: Isn't DropDownList the class name? ... shouldn't be something like dropDownList1.Items.Add ...

Comment: when I go step-by-step through it, it chrashes at
item.Text = obj["objectname"].InnerText;
but the obj is filled correctly and not null. The problem cant be item.Text because when I try it with item.Text=""; the program works

Comment: @colosso `item.Text=""` is different that `item.Text=null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is really a bad mistake. The error occures because the xpath was wrong:

```
foreach (XmlNode obj in xdoc.SelectNodes("/enabledobjects/object/*"))
    {

     RadListDataItem item = new RadListDataItem();
     item.Text = obj["objectname"].InnerText;
```

by looping like this, we try with the `obj["objectname"].InnerText` to access the "objectname" child of `<objectname>John</objectname>`.

The solution to this problems is easy:

```
foreach (XmlNode obj in xdoc.SelectNodes("/enabledobjects/object"))
    {

     RadListDataItem item = new RadListDataItem();
     item.Text = obj["objectname"].InnerText;
```

by removing /* we define the `<object>` as xmlNode object.

So the access violation was created because the child, we wanted to read out the innerText, never existed. Hope this helps someone sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not holding references loose in your code.
just in case you are trying to open a file that is already locked.
Otherwise just try "Clean Solution" änd then "Rebuild" in Visual Studio and then try again.

Comment: I don't think `XmlDocument` implements `IDisposable`